# Algorithm to check if a string is a subsequence of another string but not a subword

Tags: string, algorithm

I am trying to check if there exists a subsequence of a string s2 that is the string s1. The only caveat is the subsequence of s2 that is s1 cannot be a substring of s2.

Subsequence: 
a**b**a**c** : bc is a subsequence of the string

a**bc**d : bc is a substring and a subsequence of the string

Examples: 

s1 = "devil", s2 = "**devi**lish**l**y" True as devil is a subsequence using the last 'l' before the y to make it not a substring 
s1 = "devil", s2 = "**devil**ish" False, as devil is a subsequence but is also a substring of devilish

```
def isSubsequence(str1,str2): 
    i,j = 0, 0

    while j<len(str1) and i<len(str2): 
        if str1[j] == str2[i]:     
            j = j+1    
        i = i + 1

    return j==len(str(1))
```

I believe this is how to check if a string1 is a subsequence of string2. However, I am not sure how to add the extra property that string1 is not a subword of string2.

Anyone have any ideas on how to go about doing this.

Comment: @JessedeWit So a subword is essentially a substring

Comment: You should rephrase subsequence and subword. Perhaps define those expressions more algorithmic. You are using those expressions in a not consistent way. Btw. Your example 1 for me seems to be false. devil is a subword of devilishly, according to the definition.

Comment: I rephrased it to be more clear. Regarding example 1, essentially as long as there is a way to build a subsequence that is not just a substring, then the algorithm should return true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get a more algorithmic solution by modifying your code to track whether the subsequence matched so far will extend to a contiguous subsequence. To wit,

```
def isNoncontiguousSubsequence(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) <= 1:
        return False
    j = 0
    contiguous = True
    for c in str2:
        if str1[j] == c:
            if j < len(str1) - 1:
                j += 1
            elif contiguous:
                contiguous = False
            else:
                return True
        elif j > 0:
            contiguous = False
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a regex with greedy wildcards in between `d.*e.*v.*i.*l` 
Then check of the size of the match is greater than the length of the word (5 for "devil")

Not so pretty python program:

```
import re

def issubsequence(str1, str2):    
    regex = ".*".join(list(str1))
    m = re.search(regex,str2)
    return m is not None and len(m.group()) > len(str1)
```

Comment: How can you build a regex for an arbitrary input string

Comment: The regex solution works, I still wonder if there is a more algorithmic way to do this though?

Comment: It will be difficult to code up from scratch. Regex is a good way to start and very flexible if you want to add other constraints.